# Ошибка при открытии нового Activity

Tags: java, android

При попытке открыть новый activity из пункта меню выкидывает из программы. Почему?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_about) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Код второго activity:

```
public class AboutActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
    }
}
```

Код в string.xml:

```
<string name="action_about">О программе</string>
<string name="about_title">О программе</string>
```

Код activity_about:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/about_text"
        android:gravity="center" />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Вторая активити прописана в манифесте? Покажите стек-трейс.

Comment: Да, прописана. Как посмотреть стек-трейс? Я на реальном устройстве запускаю приложение.

Comment: Подключите это устройство к компьютеру и посмотрите. И, кстати, в `strings.xml` нет строки `about_text`.

Comment: эта строка есть, я просто не выложил там длинный текст. Студия ругалась на атрибут android:layout_height="wrap_content" у textview. Добавил и заработало. Но у меня такой вопрос. Вторая activity открывается, но на весь экран. т.е. не видно сверху названия приложения. Как это исправить? Тема стоит во обеих activity AppTheme